# Expected type after as

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm developing an app which uses google location search widget to fill the location where the user was born in, but I'm getting the issue you can see right below:

```
private class func doRequest(_ urlString: String, params: [String: String], success: (NSDictionary) -> ()) {
    if let url = URL(string: "\(urlString)?\(query(params))") {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        let session = URLSession.shared()
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            self.handleResponse(data, response: response as?, error: error, success: success)
        }
                    
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear :  *response as? **what?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as?` is use to cast one type to another, you are asking Xcode to cast `response` to another type, but haven't told it what to cast it to.

As the error says, its expecting to see a type after the keyword `as`

Comment: `handleResponse` is expecting 4 parameters. The data returned, the response, a callback to handle the error case and a callback for the successful case. You have attempted to cast the response object to the type that `handleResponse` is expecting, but haven't supplied any type. The answer is either delete `as?` because you don't need to cast, or add the type `handleResponse` is expecting, after the keyword `as?`. I can't tell you the answer because I don't have access to the code.

Comment: thank you for response though.. Somehow I found the answer.. actually the code went wrong with upgrade of swift 2.3 to swift 3.. :)